Angularfire: how to Initialize the config dynamically?
app.config.ts file:
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() =>
      initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'xxx',
        authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'xxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxx',
        messagingSenderId: '123',
        appId: 'xxx',
        measurementId: 'xxx',
      }),
    ),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})

I don't like to provide the Firebase config right at the beginning... I like to initializeApp dynamically in app.component.ts or through APP_INITIALIZER. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

do you mean you want to get it from an API?

Yes. By loading a JSON file.

from a backend API or assets folder is fine?

From assets folder is also fine :)

Initialization using API:
We create a method to fetch the json file from assets folder, then an async function that gets the config with the firebase config object.
function loadConfig() {
  return fetch('/assets/firebase.json')
      .then(response => response.json());
}

const getAppConfig = async () => {
  const config = await loadConfig();

  return {
    providers: [
        provideFirebaseApp(() =>
          initializeApp(config),
        ),
        provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
        ...
      ],
      ...
    };
};

Now, we will use this config and bootstrap our application.
(async () => {
  const config = await getAppConfig();
  bootstrapApplication(App, config);
})();


Instead of going for assets, try using environments of angular, you can add the environment variables inside the file, then add the environments path to .gitignore so that you do not commit it to github.
ng generate environments

Use the above command to install environments in your angular project.
Then add the config to this file.
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'http://my-prod-url',
  firebaseConfig: {
        apiKey: 'xxx',
        authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'xxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxx',
        messagingSenderId: '123',
        appId: 'xxx',
        measurementId: 'xxx',
  },
};

Finally access this and initialize firebase.
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() =>
      initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    ),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})


No. This is actually not useful for me :) I like it to be loaded dynamically from a JSON file. Because based on the structure that my app is going to be built in, the JSON will be modified by some other back-end app. So my already compiled Angular app should be able to load it and configure Firebase settings.

@Ali updated my answer with an alternative approach.
